# How to exclude a facet range field using SOLR?

Tags: php, solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a product_rating field in solr which is like below

```
<int name="product_rating:[4 TO 5]">6</int>
<int name="product_rating:[3 TO 5]">8</int>
<int name="product_rating:[2 TO 5]">9</int>
<int name="product_rating:[1 TO 5]">14</int>
```

So If I select anyone of this filter ,I don't want to change the facet count.But If I select any filter other than product_rating I want to change this filter count.How will this possible? (Actually I want to know how solr exclude work in facet range). plz help :)

I used this query but not working

```
q=*&fq={!tag=dt}product_rating:[4%20TO%205]&facet.field={!ex=dt}product_rating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you've tried and [as the manual say](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-LocalParametersforFaceting)s, but you have to remember that you're using `facet.range` to provide your field name - not `facet.field`.

```
facet.range={!ex=dt}id&..&fq={!tag=dt}id:[0 TO 100000]
```

.. gives the expected result (where the counts for the facet is unaffected by the `fq`).

Comment: This seems fine. So If I want to make a range like this [1-5] ,[2-5],[3-5],[4-5] using facet.range how is it possible?. I did it with facet.query .but the exclude is not working with facet.query                                                           

`<lst name="facet_counts"> <lst name="facet_queries"> <int name="product_rating:[4 TO 5]">864</int> <int name="product_rating:[3 TO 5]">1548</int> <int name="product_rating:[2 TO 5]">1935</int> <int name="product_rating:[1 TO 5]">2186</int> </lst> `

Comment: I Used the below query    `q=*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.query={!ex=dt}product_rating&fq={!tag=dt}product_ra‌​ting:[1%20TO%205]` and I am getting    `<int name="product_rating:[4 TO 5]">0</int>
<int name="product_rating:[3 TO 5]">0</int>
<int name="product_rating:[2 TO 5]">0</int>
<int name="product_rating:[1 TO 5]">2186</int>`. Plz help

Comment: You missed the = after  facet.range and I used this also   `facet=true&facet.query=product_rating:[1%20TO%205]&facet.query=product_rating:[2%20TO%205]` but this is also not working.I am not getting any facet queries